# select query to list all rows in chronological order?

Tags: sql

how to write a select query to list all rows in chronological order,with undated records appearing last?

```
    Create Table Demo(Col1 VARCHAR(10), Col2 SMALLDATETIME NULL)

    Insert into Demo Values('TG', '2009-03-08')
    Insert into Demo Values('YG', NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNULL()` to supply a large value for null values that will come after all others in your ordering.

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Demo 
ORDER BY ISNULL(Col2, '2079-1-1')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` (and your RDBMS supports it), you can force non-null values for `Col2` to sort ahead of NULLs by assigning them a lower value (0) than the NULLs (1).  The second column to `ORDER BY` is `Col2` as is, so the non-null dates will sort in ascending order.

```
SELECT 
  Col1, 
  Col2 
FROM Demo
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  Col2 ASC
```